# How to call one controller's function from another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-1.6

I was wondering if is it possible to call one controller's function from another controller. This way i tried but failed:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
        <button ng-click="func1()">func1</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
        <button ng-click="func2()">func2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope) {

  $scope.func1 = function() {
    alert('Ctrl1 and func1')
  }

    $scope.$on("MyFunction", function () {
        alert('Ctrl1 MyFunction')
    });
});

app.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope) {

  $scope.func2 = function() {
    alert('Ctrl2 and func2')
    $scope.$emit("MyFunction");
  }

});
```

when func2 is calling then i used `$scope.$emit("MyFunction");` to call Ctrl1 `MyFunction` but it does not worked. so is it not possible ?

please put some light here.

Comment: maybe typo error u missed the `$` `$scope.$emit("MyFunction");`

Comment: i fixed it but still no luck......would u see the code

Comment: try `$scope.$broadcast("MyFunction")`

Comment: still no luck. see my jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/s3s23jgo/

Comment: you could also declare you functions from $rootscope and share them that way. even better you could declare your functions as a service and use angulars dependency injection to inject your service into your controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you wanted to communicate with sibiling controllers you have to catch the event($on) using `rootScope`. use this

```
$rootScope.$on("MyFunction", function () {
            alert('Ctrl1 MyFunction')
});
```

Demo

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope,$rootScope) {

  $scope.func1 = function() {
    alert('Ctrl1 and func1')
  }

    $rootScope.$on("MyFunction", function () {
        alert('Ctrl1 MyFunction')
    });
});

app.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope) {

  $scope.func2 = function() {
    alert('Ctrl2 and func2')
    $scope.$emit("MyFunction");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
        <button ng-click="func1()">func1</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
        <button ng-click="func2()">func2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes it worked but you said another approach like "even better you could declare your functions as a service and use angulars dependency injection to inject your service into your controller" so would show this approach too in second example. this is just a request because i am new in angular

Comment: it is not suitable for this approach. since you want to go to a controller function from another controller then this approach is okay

Answer (score 2):

As you asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414525/how-to-call-one-controllers-function-from-another-controller#comment75828570_44414670) for a solution using a service, here is an example.

I created 2 controllers (`FirstCtrl`, `SecondCtrl`) that use a single service (`Data`).

Note that the function `alertName()` is defined on the service, and each controller can use it because the service is [**injected**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) in each controller.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('Data', function() {
  var name = 'Mistalis';
  return {
    alertName: function() {
      alert(name);
    }
  };
});

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, Data) {
  $scope.showName = function() {
    Data.alertName();
  }
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, Data) {
  $scope.showName = function() {
    Data.alertName();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    Controller 1<br/>
    <button ng-click="showName()">Show name from service</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
    Controller 2<br/>
    <button ng-click="showName()">Show name from service</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have seen your code but it just show how to controller can call a common function but how this approach can be used by 2 controllers to share data in each other or share data in each other ?

Comment: @MonojitSarkar Like in [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/q9ctyL6j/1/)?

Answer (score 2):

Use `$rootScope.$broadcast`:

```
app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope) {

  $scope.func1 = function() {
    alert('Ctrl1 and func1')
  }

    $scope.$on("MyFunction", function () {
        alert('Ctrl1 MyFunction')
    });
});

app.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope, $rootScope) {

  $scope.func2 = function() {
    alert('Ctrl2 and func2')
    //$scope.$emit("MyFunction");
    //USE rootScope
    $rootScope.$broadcast("MyFunction");
  }

});
```

**Best practice:**  To avoid memory leaks, avoid using `$on` listeners on `$rootScope`. Listeners on `$scope` will be properly destroyed automatically when controllers are removed.

For more information on the AngularJS event bus, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Event Propagation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-events-propagation)
- [AngularJS rootScope/scope API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)